# ClientSide Validation on PrimeFaces Wizard

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, wizard

For wizard forms, is there any way we can configure the primefaces 4.0 make and client side validation instead of ajax validation?!

According to user guide the ajax validation is built in:

> AJAX and Partial Validations
>
> Switching between steps is based on ajax,
>   meaning each step is loaded dynamically with ajax. Partial validation
>   is also built-in, by this way when you click next, only the current
>   step is validated, if the current step is valid, next tab’s contents
>   are loaded with ajax. Validations are not executed when flow goes
>   back.

I think it can be done, if I can call primeface validation manually. Then below code will do the job:

```
<p:wizard showNavBar="false" widgetVar="wiz">
...
</p:wizard>
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="PF('wiz').checkClientValidation();">Next</h:outputLink>
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="PF('wiz').checkClientValidation();">Back</h:outputLink>
```

Any comments? Can I call client validation manually? Do you think above is good solution!

Comment: no! Actually I am looking if there is a such a method 'checkClientValidation' ! If there is, may it can be called this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a commandButton instead of `outputLink` and set the `validateClient=true` attribute.
Validations happen in the `ValidationsPhase`, so its partially client side only.
You don't need to trigger validation manually on the client side.
Is there any reason you have to use the `outputLink` ?

If you want to check the status of validations on the client side then you can use :
Example :

```
oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){PF('dialogId').show(); }"
```